# Dont know how to split .dat file lines

Tags: python-3.x

so I have this project that needs me to read a .dat file and convert it into a table, the .dat file goes like this:

```
50123456_lam tai man_70.0_60.0_
50223456_li tai man_60.0_90.5_
50323456_wong tai man_34.5_30.0_
50423456_ng tai man_90.5_70.0_
50523456_lau tai man_86.0_92.4_
50623456_chui tai man_70.0_64.5_
50723456_lim tai man_64.5_60.0_
50823456_pok tai man_37.5_35.50_
50923456_kim tai man_92.4_60.0_
50023456_tsang tai man_15.0_20.0_
50999999_chan peter_100.00_80.00_
```

I wish to split the lines by their underscores so I can make a list with each element.
As Im an amateur I can now only import the files into my program, I still need to figure out the way to split the lines into usable variables.

This is the import program in question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fileinput
import sys

def main():
    lineNum = 0
    for line in fileinput.input('markdata.dat'):
        lineNum += 1
        sys.stdout.write(str(lineNum)+' ')
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If anyone would like to help I'm appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv library should meet your needs if all you want to do is to split them by underscores. Here's an example; just change the delimiter to an underscore.

```
import csv

with open('my_sample_data.dat') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        print(row)

>>>
['Date', 'Time', 'Event', 'OrgID', 'Email']
['12/15/2018', '6:55:41 AM', 'abc', '1', 'abc@email.com']
['12/15/2018', '1:36:39 PM', 'def', '2', 'def@email.com']
['12/15/2018', '2:21:56 PM', 'com', '3', 'com@email.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

The good way to deal with such dat files is using pandas library. You read this file in Dataframe and using delimiter as underscore.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.dat',delimiter='_',header=None)
```